# sas collapsing categorical variables clustering analysis

Tags: sas, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I came across the following code in the logistic regression modeling course offered by SAS:

```
data dataset(drop=i);
set data;

array mi{*} mi_Ag mi_Inc
mi_WR;

array x{*} Ag Inc WR;
do i=1 to dim(mi);
mi{i}=(x{i}=.);
end;
run;
```

I need to understand two things:

1.) there is a column created titled "i" once this data step is run. What does that signify and why is there. The drop "i" essentially drops it but if i don't use drop option the column stays in the data set

2.) this do step is replacing all the missing values with a 1 and rest with 0. How is that happening when nothing is clearly specified in the do step as to what needs to be done. In my eyes, "do i=1 to dim(mi); mi{i}=(x{i}=.);" should simply put dots in mi(i) wherever it finds dots in x(i).

Part 2:

While collapsing the categorical variable, following code has been used:

```
proc freq data=example1 noprint;
  tables CLUSTER_CODE*TARGET_B / chisq;
  output out=out_chi(keep=_pchi_) chisq;
run;

data ex_cutoff;
  if _n_=1 then set out_chi;
  set ex_cluster;
  chisquare=_pchi_*rsquared;
  degfree=numberofclusters-1;
  logpvalue=logsdf('CHISQ',chisquare,degfree);
run;
```

what is *n*=1 doing ? and also, why are we creating chisquare=_pchi*rsquared. *pchi* is already chisquare so whats the point of multiplying it with R square?

Thanks

P.S. The code is from one of the SAS learning courses. Hopefully I am allowed to share it here for discussion/learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

i is the array iterator (created in the `do` loop).  It's dropped since it's not really intended to be kept on the dataset, it's just an iterator (letting you go through the array one element at a time and during that iteration letting you reference a single element).

`mi{i}=(x{i}=.);` is assigning 1/0 like this:

`x(i)=.` is either true or false.  If it is `true`, it evaluates to a `1`.  If it is `false`, it evaluates to `0`.   Thus when it's true that x(i)=. then m(i) is assigned a 1; otherwise it is assigned a 0.  That's just how SAS works with boolean (True/False) values; many other langauges work that way as well (True is nonzero, False is zero); and when converted to number, True is converted to 1 (but any nonzero nonmissing value is 'True' when converted the other way around).

Comment: Thank you Joe - much appreciated. so im sensing that anytime in a do statement if i were to test for =. then it will act like a true/false (1/0) test?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the Do statement - any time it is on the right side of an assignment (=).